# What quests become unavailable after "Capture the Castle"?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am up to the main quest "Capture the Castle" in the *Blood & Wine* DLC. While going to the mission, I got a warning telling me that doing this quest may result in some side quests becoming unavailable, so I've decided to not do it just yet.

I've read that there aren't any quests that become unavailable regardless of the result of this quest, but why would the game bother prompting the player with a warning if that was the case?

So my question is: what (if any) side quests could become unavailable after I complete "Capture the Castle"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to a user [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/4mslx7/spoilers_side_quests_after_capture_the_castle/), there is only *one* side quest that becomes unavailable after completing Capture the Castle:

> The only quest you need to finish before Capture the Castle is Warble of a Smitten Knight.

The same thing is said [in this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/4m48yj/which_quests_are_disabled_by_the_capture_the/):

> I think its just the Warble of a Smitten Knight quest.
>
> When I did it all that failed was warble of a smitten knight, everything else was fine

Lastly, [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/350532536099648258/) supports this, as well:

> Only "The Warble of a Smitten Knight" as far as I know.
>
> yes just smitten knight quest, is the only one that comes up "failed" when you progress to the next stage

Thus, it looks like as long as you finish "The Warble of a Smitten Knight," you won't miss out on anything by completing Capture the Castle.

Answer (score 5):

It is just the 'Warble of a Smitten Knight' quest.

If you examine the various bodies you come across (if you opt to find Damien) during the 'The Night of Long Fangs' quest that follows on from 'Capture the Castle' you will discover why you need to do 'Warble of a Smitten Knight' first.

Spoiler:

> Guillaume dies fighting alongside Damien

Answer (score 0):

Look out for Amidst the Mill's Grist quest in Blood and Wine.

It didn't show up as failed on first play through but it is a quest that is available to complete while being very easy to miss. It has to be played right after completing La Cage au Fou and before starting or completing Where Children Toil, Toys Waste Away.

It doesn't popup as a secondary quest automatically. It has to be triggered by being in the Count de la Croix's Mill area after La Cage and since its optional it won't show up as failed if you didn't attempt it.

An additional warning, people have ran into the same glitch for different reasons.

Make sure you have a couple of saves of La Cage au Fou prior to completing because I ran in to a version of the glitch with Amidst the Mill's Grist. I guess, depending on what you did or didn't do in the area of this quest prior could cause different issues for not being able to complete.

In my case, I had to go back to a save before completing La Cage au Fou. Run over to Count de la Croix's Mill, where this quest is located, get the sign post available, look around but didn't pick anything up. Went back and complete La Cage. After that I was able to go directly to Croix's Mill to trigger and complete the Amidst the Mill's Grist.

I hope it helps with any others with osd to complete all quests.

Comment: How do any of these quests relate to "Capture the Castle"?